Upgrade to 24 LTS from 22.04 trashed all network config no wireless nor ethernet
I upgraded to Ubuntu  24LTS via the yellow upgrade button in the status bar. The installation was "successful". On rebooting no wifi icon in the top status bar, and there is no ethernet conectivity, so I cant attach logs (I'm writing this on my tablet). Cannot run any package package installation because there is no wifi nor ethernet.
Systemctl status systemd_resolvd.service is working - service has green ok status.
Netplan status --all
Says the devices wlo0 and ethernet are DOWN. There are active dummy services.
I cannot go back to 22.04 kernel because the upgrade removed the old stuff. Thanks Ubuntu.
How do I fix this by hand withput internet? What are the magic incantations requured.
Thanks.

If you boot from a 24.04 LiveUSB, and enter the "Try Ubuntu" environment, then does your wireless work?

"I cannot go back to 22.04 kernel because the upgrade removed the old stuff." That is a suspicious clue. A normal release-upgrade keeps the last working kernel precisely in case something like this happens. Were you offered a "partial upgrade?" Are you completely sure that an older kernel is not available via GRUB?

I agree with user535733. Unless you already have Boot Repair installed, you could install it on a usb stick from another machine and run it. Then at least you could have access to the older version, which should be present.
